# Tap and Long press gesture for Button with a label

Tags: ios, button, ipad, swiftui, tap

I am trying to add a long press gesture to the tap gesture that I have already implemented in my button but I can't do it. I have already tried with the

```
.gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 2)
         .onEnded { 
                    //do something
                   }
         )
```

or with the

```
.onTapGesture {
                //do something
              }
```

But it doesn't work for me because I don't know where put it in place in the code. I have already tried to put it after the Button but usually I have an error with the line

```
label:
```

This is the code :

```
struct MyButton: View {

    var myRow: String
    @Binding var oneTap: [Bool]
    @Binding var textInButton: String
    @Binding var arrayIndice: Int
    var arrayLocalIndice : Int
    @Binding var allWords: [String]
    @Binding var onlyOneButtonSelected: Bool

    var body: some View {
                Button{
                    if (oneTap[arrayLocalIndice] == true){
                        onlyOneButtonSelected = false
                        oneTap[arrayLocalIndice] = false
                        textInButton = ""
                        arrayIndice = 0
                    }
                    else if (onlyOneButtonSelected == false){
                        onlyOneButtonSelected = true
                        oneTap[arrayLocalIndice] = true
                        textInButton = myRow
                        arrayIndice = arrayLocalIndice
                    }
                } label:{
                    ULD(title: myRow, textColor: .black, backgroundColor: (oneTap[arrayLocalIndice]) ? .red : .green)
                }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can add a long press gesture recognizer to a `Button` by using `.simultaneousGesture()`. Your code would look like this:

```
            Button{
                if (oneTap[arrayLocalIndice] == true){
                    onlyOneButtonSelected = false
                    oneTap[arrayLocalIndice] = false
                    textInButton = ""
                    arrayIndice = 0
                }
                else if (onlyOneButtonSelected == false){
                    onlyOneButtonSelected = true
                    oneTap[arrayLocalIndice] = true
                    textInButton = myRow
                    arrayIndice = arrayLocalIndice
                }
            } label:{
                ULD(title: myRow, textColor: .black, backgroundColor: (oneTap[arrayLocalIndice]) ? .red : .green)
            }
            .simultaneousGesture(
                LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 2)
                    .onEnded {_ in
                        //do something
                    }
            )
```

And, you don't even need a `Button` at all. You could simply do this:

```
    ULD(title: myRow, textColor: .black, backgroundColor: (oneTap[arrayLocalIndice]) ? .red : .green)
        .onTapGesture {
            if (oneTap[arrayLocalIndice] == true){
                onlyOneButtonSelected = false
                oneTap[arrayLocalIndice] = false
                textInButton = ""
                arrayIndice = 0
            }
            else if (onlyOneButtonSelected == false){
                onlyOneButtonSelected = true
                oneTap[arrayLocalIndice] = true
                textInButton = myRow
                arrayIndice = arrayLocalIndice
            }
        }
        .simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 2)
            .onEnded {
                //do something
            }
        )
```

Either way, without a `simultaneousGesture()`, you can't add a second gesture recognizer as the view will only recognize the first gesture(and a button has its own `.tapGesture()` recognizer).